# The uploaded glossary doesn't seem to be used when requesting a translation

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-translate

I have successfully uploaded an equivalent term glossary resource which I can list and also get returned as the used glossary when requesting a translation, but I don't get the expected results to terms that I included in the glossary.

The glossary has the term "High beam" in english, paired with the correct english translation "Távolsági fényszóró", and the term "Low beam" paired with "Tompított fényszóró" in the uploaded .csv file like so:

```
en,hu,pos
High beam,Távolsági fényszóró,noun
Low beam,Tompított fényszóró,noun
```

and my code:

```
from google.cloud import translate_v3beta1 as translate_v3


eng = "H1 High beam, H1 Low beam"
pid = "[HIDDEN]"
gid = "kittglossary"


def translate_text_with_glossary(
    text,
    project_id,
    glossary_id,
):
    """Translates a given text using a glossary."""

    client = translate_v3.TranslationServiceClient()
    parent = 'projects/[HIDDEN]/locations/us-central1'

    glossary = client.glossary_path(
        project_id, "us-central1", glossary_id  # The location of the glossary
    )

    glossary_config = translate_v3.types.TranslateTextGlossaryConfig(
        glossary=glossary, ignore_case=True)

    # Supported language codes: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/languages
    response = client.translate_text(
        request={
            "contents": [text],
            "source_language_code": "en",
            "target_language_code": "hu",            
            "parent": parent,
            "glossary_config": glossary_config,
           }
    )
    print("Translated text: \n")
    for translation in response.glossary_translations:
        print(u"\t {}".format(translation.translated_text))
        print(u"\t {}".format(translation.glossary_config))


translate_text_with_glossary(eng,pid,gid)
```

But the resulting translation gives me an incorrect translation that doesn't seem to use my glossary:

```
Translated text:

         H1 tompított fény, H1 tompított fény
         glossary: "projects/[HIDDEN}/locations/us-central1/glossaries/kittglossary"
ignore_case: true
```

The correct translation should be "H1 Távolsági fényszóró, H1 Tompított fényszóró" using the glossary I provided.

I would appreciate any help